# group tibble rows by unordered combination of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

Given the following tibble

```
tibble(sample = c(1:6),
       string = c("ABC","ABC","CBA","FED","DEF","DEF"),
       x = c("a","a","b","e","d","d"),
       y = c("b","b","a","d","e","e"))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  sample string x     y    
   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1      1 ABC    a     b    
2      2 ABC    a     b    
3      3 CBA    b     a    
4      4 FED    e     d    
5      5 DEF    d     e    
6      6 DEF    d     e
```

I would like to group rows by the unordered combination of columns `x,y`, then flip `x` ⇔ `y` and reverse `string` in instances where `x,y` is inverted relative to the first row in the group. The desired output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  sample string x     y     group
   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1      1 ABC    a     b         1
2      2 ABC    a     b         1
3      3 ABC    a     b         1
4      4 FED    e     d         2
5      5 FED    e     d         2
6      6 FED    e     d         2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
strSort <- function(x) sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")

dat %>% 
  group_by(group = data.table::rleid(strSort(string))) %>% 
  mutate(across(string:y, first))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
  sample string x     y     group
   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <int>
1      1 ABC    a     b         1
2      2 ABC    a     b         1
3      3 ABC    a     b         1
4      4 FED    e     d         2
5      5 FED    e     d         2
6      6 FED    e     d         2
```

---

Previous answer

Here's a way using both `tidyverse` and `apply` approaches. First, sort the rows of columns x and y, then `group_by` x and y, create a `cur_group_id` and `stri_reverse` if necessary.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

#Sort by row
dat[, c("x", "y")] <- t(apply(dat[, c("x", "y")], 1, sort))

dat %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>% 
  mutate(group = cur_group_id(),
         string = ifelse(str_sub(string, 1, 1) == toupper(x), string, stri_reverse(string)))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   x, y [2]
  sample string x     y     group
   <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <int>
1      1 ABC    a     b         1
2      2 ABC    a     b         1
3      3 ABC    a     b         1
4      4 DEF    d     e         2
5      5 DEF    d     e         2
6      6 DEF    d     e         2
```

Comment: This is very helpful and answers most of my question, but I'd like to preserve the order of the first row in each group. Note row 4 in my input and rows 4-6 in my desired output.

Comment: @acvill see my edit.